# How do I remove invalid characters from UTF-8 encoded file?

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

**Explanation**:

I've come across an edge case when writing my web app. I accept UTF-8 files to be uploaded, and I've got a check in place to confirm it is UTF-8 encoded (or at least the best check possible, apparently there is no silver bullet, I'm aware there are many other questions on Stack Overflow for that specific issue).

As a test, I took an ANSI encoded file and converted it to UTF-8 by both (in separate tests) converting it UTF-8 in Notepad++, and also by just decoding as UTF-8 (even though it is ANSI) on the fly in C# using `Encoding.UTF.GetBytes(inputStream)`.

**Where The Problem Arises**:

Later on, I place the raw data of the file as one of the elements in an XML file. This is where the problem arises. It appears that a character has persisted from the ANSI file which (I assume) is not valid in UTF-8. When I try load the XML using the following command...

`XDocument xmlSample = XDocument.Load(outputPath);`

I get this exception...

`{"Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 10, position 14."}`

Which looks like this in Visual Studio...

[image: VSImg]

And like this in Notepad++...

[image: NPPImg]

Below is the character copy and pasted.

From NPP: `¡` From Visual Studio String Viewer: `�`

**Question**:

How can I remove invalid characters from UTF-8 encoded file, or at least discover them in a sane way so I can reject the file?

Comment: Copy and paste the character into the question, it might give some clues.

Comment: XmlReader.Create(string, settings) you can add a settings parameter to ignore character checking.  It doesn't always work but may in your case.  The temperature symbol is not illegal in xml, it just the Microsoft Implementation requires special handling of these characters.

Comment: I copy and pasted the character.

Comment: And can you show the original character? `�` (`FFFD`) is a [Replacement Character](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFFF0.pdf): "used to replace an incoming character whose value is unknown or unrepresentable in Unicode", whereas `¡` (`C2A1`) is [invalid](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/c2a1/index.htm). I assume visual studio is replacing correctly with the replacement char, and npp is doing something weird. Note you can get the code through `BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("�"))`

Comment: The MSDN has a page [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/844skk0h(v=vs.110).aspx) that uses Regex and however it has `\w` defined to filter out "invalid characters". It seemed to worked with the two chars you showed here, but I don't know if it ends up stripping useful chars or not.

Comment: In Notepad++, did you use the Encode As or Convert To in order to reencode? Encode As only presents the bytes as they were read from the disk using the newly selected encoding. Since ANSI and UTF-8 are different above character 127, it could produce unexpected results. The Convert To entries in the Encoding menu actually take the characters and properly convert them to the newly selected encoding.

Comment: @Kevin I used Convert To, but it still thinks that character is invalid when I try to run `XDocument.Load(outputPath);`

Comment: How do you currently check UTF-8 validity? It seems that this test isn't thorough enough.

Answer (score 2):

First, as to your example, the word “Temperature” suggests that the offending character is in fact the “degree” sign (°, Unicode 176), so that the full text reads “Temperature(°C)”. In this case the character would be coded as a `\260` byte in ANSI and as the two bytes `\302\260` in UTF-8. `\260`(preceded by the left parenthesis in this case) is not valid UTF-8.

Second – if you are still interested after more than a year – could you clarify how you use `Encoding.UTF.GetBytes()`to “decode a file as UTF-8?” `GetBytes()`reads characters, not bytes, and characters in C# do not have an encoding; the encoding has been applied when reading the file and converting it into characters. What `UTF.GetBytes()` does is *encode* (not *decode*) the characters into a UTF-8 byte sequence.

In order to check an incoming byte sequence you might use `Encoding.UTF.GetChars()` to decode your byte sequence into characters. Depending on the constructor you use you can get a “cleaned-up” character string (with data loss if problems occurred) or receive a `DecoderFallbackException` on offending byte sequences, so you can reject the input.